# Getting the WebRole module inside my Azure web role app to read web.config settings

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I understand that the WebRole module inside my Web Role web app project runs inside WAIISHost.exe and the rest of the app runs inside W3WP.EXE.  Therefore web.config settings cannot be read from the WebRole app domain.

This can be solved by creating a special "waiishost.exe.config" in the web project file and set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy Always".

That's fine.  However, now, I have config settings in ServiceConfiguration AND web.config AND "waiishost.exe.config".  This is only a minor but annoying issue though.  The biggest problem is that when I publish my Azure project, ServiceConfiguration and web.config get automatically transformed into the production values whereas waiishost.exe.config does not get transformed, so I end up with development config going into the production environment.  (the production env is not live yet, so not a major issue **yet**)

Can anyone think of any ideas as to how I can also have the Publish process transform waiishost.exe.config? Maybe I could run some kind of startup process which could simply copy and rename the web.config file to be waiishost.exe.config *before* waiishost.exe starts.

BTW, I cannot simply move config to the ServiceConfiguration file as I have whole config sections and connection strings which are used by third party components, like the ServiceBusConfiguration section.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.

A little manual, but is "one-time-setup" per project. Check out [this](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/10/servicereferenceclientconfig-build.html) and [that](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/06/windows-azure-configuration-settings.html) blog posts I've made a while ago (even before you could have ServiceConfiguration files). These blog posts will give you a great idea on how to achieve your desire.